# Write longest and shortest palindrome from text file

Tags: c#, arrays, string, text-files, palindrome

I am trying to write a program what will write longest and shortest palindrome from words in text file. My code looks like this now:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\palindromy.txt");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            char[] charArray = line.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Array.Reverse(charArray);
                bool a = charArray.SequenceEqual(line);
                while(a == true)
                {                        
                    Console.WriteLine(line); /that will just write all palindroms
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am currently just writing all palindromes, but I need to write just longest and shortest one.

Comment: Store longest palindrome in variable, then write variable after foreach. PS. dont use while to execute single instruction, its will be better to use if (a) { Console.WriteLine }

Comment: You also have a for loop that iterates exactly once...

Comment: Add two new variables called shortest and longest. Change while(a == true) to simply if (a). Inside of this scope, check if the length of the palindrome is greater than your longest variable and set it if it is. Same with the shortest variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to previous answer but with the following suggestions

1. Initialize longest and shortest.
2. Ignore case when comparing. Could still do this with SequenceEqual instead of comparing strings. May not be needed if you know you won't be comparing Anna to annA.
3. When checking if you found the shortest you need to remember that
   shortest.Length with be 0 to start so you will want to store the first palindrome found in shortest if shortest.Length==0.

   ```
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\palindromy.txt");

       string longest = string.Empty;
       string shortest = string.Empty;

       foreach (var line in lines)
       {
           if (line.Length == 0) continue;

           char[] charArray = line.ToCharArray();
           Array.Reverse(charArray);
           string reversedLine = new string(charArray);

           if (line.Equals(reversedLine, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
           {
               if (line.Length > longest.Length)
               {
                   longest = line;
               }
               if (line.Length < shortest.Length || shortest.Length == 0)
               {
                   shortest = line;
               }
           }
       }

       Console.WriteLine(longest);
       Console.WriteLine(shortest);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\palindromy.txt");
        private string longest;
        private string shortest;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            char[] charArray = line.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Array.Reverse(charArray);
                bool a = charArray.SequenceEqual(line);
                if(a)
                {
                      if(a.Length > longest.length)
                         {
                              longest = a;
                         }
                      if(a.Length<shortest.length)
                         {
                            shortest = a;
                         }
                }
            }
        }

           Console.WriteLine(longest);
           Console.WriteLine(shortest);
    }
```

Off the top of my head it would look something like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some LINQ, you can simplify it to a great extent:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\palindromy.txt");
var palindromes = lines.Where(x => x == new string(x.ToCharArray()
                       .Reverse()
                       .ToArray()));

var shortest = palindromes.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Length < b.Length ? a : b);
var longest = palindromes.Aggregate((a, b) => a.Length > b.Length ? a : b);

Console.WriteLine("The shortest palindrome is {0}.", shortest);
Console.WriteLine("The longest palindrome is {0}.", longest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple console application that does exactly what you ask for. The words are in a `List`, so you will have to read the words from the text file and store them in the `List` yourself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PalinDromes
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            List<string> words = new List<string> () { "anotherword","civic", "deified", "lemel", "pop" ,"noon"};

            string shortest = "";
            string longest = "";

            foreach (string word in words) 
            {
                if (isPalindrome (word)) 
                {
                    if (word.Length > longest.Length)
                        longest = word;
                    else if (shortest == "" || word.Length < shortest.Length)
                        shortest = word;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine ("Shortest: {0}", shortest);
            Console.WriteLine ("Longest: {0}", longest);
        }

        public static bool isPalindrome(string word)
        {
            return word == ReverseString (word);
        }

        public static string ReverseString(string s)
        {
            char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(arr);
            return new string(arr);
        }
    }
}
```